# unexpected value at AOT compilation in angular 2

Tags: angular

i am using ng2-image upload module.when i run my project by npm run build:prod
i am getting error.
i put ImageUploadModule in my imports array
my appmodule.ts
`import { ResizeOptions, ImageResult, ImageUploadModule } from 'ng2-imageupload'; @NgModule({ declarations: [ AppComponent, ], imports: [BrowserModule, routing, FormsModule, HttpModule, ImageUploadModule], providers: [ ], bootstrap: [AppComponent] }) export class AppModule { }`

========================================================================

my Error :

### Unexpected value 'ImageUploadModule' imported by the module 'App Module'